# Как получить значение строки после символа?

Tags: база-данных, oracle

Необходимо взять значение `X` из таблицы `Y`. `X` в формате `12345_пример`. На выходе необходимо получить значение `"пример"`. Количество символов произвольное, известен только разделитель `"_"`.

Смог родить только:

```
select  case instr(NAME,'_')
    when 0 then NAME
      else substr(NAME,0,instr(NAME,'_')  -1)
    end
from  AONAME
```

Что возвращает часть до разделителя `"_"`. Как получить часть после разделителя?

Comment: `substr(NAME, instr(NAME,'_'))` или `substr(NAME, instr(NAME,'_') + 1)`.

Comment: @Visman Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, я не уверен какой из вариантов даст правильный результат.

Comment: @Visman Как мне кажется, ответ в любом случае лучше, чем комментарий!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените

```
substr(NAME,0,instr(NAME,'_')  -1)
```

на

```
substr(NAME,instr(NAME,'_')+1)
```

Тут указывается только начальная позиция для выделения подстроки и не указывается длина выделения, значит в подстроку попадают символы до конца первоначальной строки.

P.S. В обеих функциях (substr, instr) начальная позиция 1, а не 0.

Answer (score 2):

При нарушении формата `substr` возможно вернёт не совсем ожидаемый результат.
Например для: `'123 _'`,  вернёт `null`. Попробуйте следующее:

```
select regexp_replace (name, '^\d+_(\w+)$', '\1') from  (select '123_abcde' name from dual);
```

Так значение поля останется неизменным, если не будет полного совпадения по маске.